# Flyway migration success but fields are not added

Tags: java, spring-boot, migration, flyway

I'm using `Flyway` on a SpringBoot Project to manage my migrations.

These are the options in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:DB/migration
flyway.enabled = true
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
```

And these are the options in the `build.gradle` file:

```
flyway {
    url = "****"
    user = "****"
    password = "****"
    baselineOnMigrate = true
}
```

On this DB it seems the migrations were successfully applied, I can see in the `flyway_schema_history` table all the migrations with the success column set to 1.

But I can't run the application because none of the table/column of the migrations scripts were inserted in the database.